# Error when deploying maven project to Google app engine

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I was trying to deploy a maven project to Google App Engine, but whenever i use the command `mvn appengine:deploy` in cmd i get this error

```
    [INFO] GCLOUD:
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 08:43 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-21T21:43:13+07:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 22M/287M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-
    plugin:1.2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project cc_w10: Execution default-cli 
    of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.2.1:deploy failed: 
    Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Here's my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.cc_w10.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>cc_w10</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>  

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME></INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
        <user>user1</user>
        <password>1234</password>
        <database>sqldemo</database>
        <sqlURL>jdbc:mysql://google/sqldemo?cloudSqlInstance=cc-week-five:us-central1:root&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&amp;user=root&amp;password=1234&amp;useSSL=false</sqlURL>

    </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>                       
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>cc_w10</finalName>    
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.50</version>
            </plugin>   

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>      
        </plugins>    
    </build>
</project>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I've been looking for the solution for days but it seems hopeless.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59921349/8052414 , worked for me! I had changed changed my packaging to jar earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your project is a spring boot project so try using spring-maven plugin to generate the jar

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: You tried that with the apppengine plugin enabled too??

Comment: I have appengine plugin in my pom.xml, does that mean it is automatically enabled or do i have to enable it manually? If so how can i do that?

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-java-only) you are required to supply both plugins, as the 'spring-boot-maven-plugin' is used to create the JAR files for your app. You can then deploy using 'mvn appengine:deploy' which makes use of the 'appengine-maven-plugin'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and tried it a different way.

Since `appengine:deploy` didn't seem to copy my `app.yaml` but instead created its own, I tried to use gcloud commands directly on the target/appengine-staging after pasting my yaml file.

Then I run `gcloud app deploy` and it worked thanks to this line I added in `app.yaml`:

```
health_check: enable_health_check: False
```

Starting from version 1.3.0 the appengine plugin even doesn't detect my `app.yaml` in the first place. However it's set on the root folder. I suppose it requires it in a different place/folder but I don't know which one.

Comment: I updated the app and ran through the same problem again... I think it's just random timeout. I'm really surprised that such basic features are not working. I expected more from Google...

Comment: After i deployed it using     gcloud app deploy     it says "404 not found" in the project.appspot.com site although there was no error during the deployment. Do you know why and how to deploy it properly? Also when i add health_check: enable_health_ check: False to the app.yaml it says :"ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [D:\WorkSpace\cc_w10\app.yaml]
Unable to assign value 'enable_health_check' to attribute 'health_check':". Sorry for my messy comment.

Comment: I resolved the deploy errors i had by adding this to the yaml file : resources:
  memory_gb: 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late to the party, but make sure you have specified the packaging as 'war'. That solved my issue.